# PHP code displaying as comments in browser using WAMP

Tags: php, html, sql, wamp

As is says in the title, my PHP code is showing up in the browser code inspector like it is commented out. 
For example,

```
<?
include("assets/php/dbconn.inc.php");
$conn = dbConnect();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";
$rs = $conn->query($sql) or die ("Movie query failed");
$number_of_rows = $rs->num_rows;


while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()){
echo("{$row['title']}");
}
?>
```

displays in the browser as

```
<!--?
include("assets/php/dbconn.inc.php");
$conn = dbConnect();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies";
$rs = $conn--->
```

and the rest of the code prints on the webpage.

I am testing this using WAMP on my local machine. Any idea where these comment tags are coming from?

Comment: use ``<?php`` to start a php script not with the deprecated short tag ``<?``

Comment: Hi. Thanks for wanting to mark as solved, though we tend not to do that here. Would you instead accept the answer I have created? If you fix something yourself in the future, it is recommended that you create your own answer and accept that. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a minor mistake that may not be of wide interest to a future readership. Pleased it is solved though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Never** use short open tag `<?` in your PHP code. Always use long tags `<?php`, simply because `<?` can be disabled (or not enabled, may depend on distro) in `php.ini` with `short_open_tag` directive (and this looks like your culprit). In result, PHP scripts are not processed by PHP interpreter and will usually end up sent to the visitor as plain text, exposing your whole source code (but also DB credentials etc).

Comment: I've got the short tags enabled, and using <?php doesnt work either

Answer (score 2):

*Posted on behalf of the OP:*

SOLVED I was navigating to the file directly instead of through the localhost address. Rookie mistake.